# css alignment for button and inputbox

Tags: html, css

I want to display textbox first and then button.But now button appears first.I attached css code and html

```
css
   .search,.stxt{
    float: right;
    }  
html
   <form  method="POST">
     <p style="align:right;">
     <input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt"><a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
     <button name="search" class="search">Search</button></p>
   </form>
```

[image]

Comment: try removing **class="stxt"** from input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Floating Elements Next to Each Other**
If you place several floating elements after each other, they will float next to each other if there is room.

So add the same class for both elements like below

**HTML:**

```
<form  method="POST">
     <p style="align:right;">
     <input class="stxt alignLeft" type="text" name="searchtxt"><a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
     <button name="search alignLeft" class="search">Search</button></p>
   </form>
```

And remove the float:right; in the .search,.stxt classes in CSS styles and add the following CSS:

```
 .alignLeft{
    float: left;
    }  
p{
    margin-left: 290px;
}
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gvmtuo5j/1/

**Alternative:**

Try Like this:

```
.search,.stxt{
    float: left;
    }  
p{
    margin-left: 290px;
}
```

check out this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gvmtuo5j/

Comment: It works but you could never make responsive design with this :P

Comment: @WilliamN That's no problem change the margin-left px value to %

Answer (score 2):

The nature of floats will prioritise the first element in the list. This is why your input text box is to the right.

I would recommend wrapping your elements within a div and having that float to the right instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the button before your input text :

```
<form  method="POST">
     <p style="align:right;">
     <button name="search" class="search">Search</button></p>
     <input class="stxt" type="text" name="searchtxt"><a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
</form>
```

Or the simpliest way is to put the float right on your `<p>` tag and remove the others float right